# Should I remove Angular watches?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-scope

I'm developing a search engine inside angular view and I was wondering if search engine is used too many times and the user does not leave the search engine's view, how should I do to avoid the problem of overloading scope?

When I carry out a lot of searches, I can notice the view is slower. I think this problem is caused by scope overload, but I'm not sure.

An example:
If I get the results of a request into `$scope.variable1` and after I make another request again and overwrite `$scope.variable1.`..what happen? are watchers of data structure inside old `variable1` removed automatically?

In summary, sometimes when I use too many times an angular views without leaving it the view is slowed down. Which is the best practice to deal with it?

Comment: That smells of a memory leak. Use the Heap Allocation Timeline of Chrome Dev Tools to check whether you are retaining memory.

Answer (score 3):

Anytime a scope variable changes a digest cycle is triggered meaning all watchers are checked to see if anything has changed. ( actually 2 times for dirty checking ). In a search field you should throttle how many times you update your scope variable otherwise the digest cycle will kick in too much. you can do this with 
debounce

```
<input type="text" name="variable1"
             ng-model="variable1"
             ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
```

Also make sure you are not creating a new watcher when $scope.variable1 changes. declare the watcher once in your controller

Anytime you use:

```
{{variable}}
```

you are implicitely creating a watcher on that page. 
Whenever your page contains more than 2000 watchers you will see slowing of the page because the digest cycle will take to long for it to be snappy

you can use this snippet to count the number of watchers on your page :

```
(function () { 
    var root = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('body'));

    var watchers = [];

    var f = function (element) {
        angular.forEach(['$scope', '$isolateScope'], function (scopeProperty) { 
            if (element.data() && element.data().hasOwnProperty(scopeProperty)) {
                angular.forEach(element.data()[scopeProperty].$$watchers, function (watcher) {
                    watchers.push(watcher);
                });
            }
        });

        angular.forEach(element.children(), function (childElement) {
            f(angular.element(childElement));
        });
    };

    f(root);

    // Remove duplicate watchers
    var watchersWithoutDuplicates = [];
    angular.forEach(watchers, function(item) {
        if(watchersWithoutDuplicates.indexOf(item) < 0) {
             watchersWithoutDuplicates.push(item);
        }
    });

    console.log(watchersWithoutDuplicates.length);
})();
```

if to many watches exist consider using:

```
{{::variable}}
```

this will create a one time binding and eliminate some watchers on your page.
Another tip is to use pagination for your search results, this will also limit the amount of watchers on your page

and lastely you probably shouldnt use watchers to begin with.
read this article:

[probably dont need watchers](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html)

Kind regards,

Comment: I used the function to measure watchers and I realised that's not a watchers problem. When I make the first search I have 736 watchers, and I tried to make 10 searches more before leave the view and I measured watchers again (736 again). My watchers' number is between 736 and 1300 in the worst case.

Comment: @Serginho 736 watches looks like a high amount of watches to me. wht $watch function returns a deregistration function for the created listener. You can use it if in some moment the watch is not necesary

Comment: I'm remembering that one think that slows down my app is when I use the chrome plugin named ng-inspector. if I activate it and desactivate it, the app  slows down but the number of watches is the same.

Comment: @Raulucco An example: when I pass to second step in my app I have 1300 watchers and app works fast. But if I start and stop ng-inspector, and come back to step 1, I have 736 watchers and my app works very very slow. I don't underestand.